# Write-Through No-Write-Allocate Penalty Calculation

Tags: caching, memory

I am considering a **write through**, **no write allocate** (write no allocate) cache. I understand these by the following definitions:

- Write Through: information is written to both the block in the cache and to the block in the lower-level memory
- no write allocate: on a Write *miss*,  the block is modified in the main memory and not loaded into the cache.
- t<sub>cache</sub> : the time it takes to access the first level of cache
- t<sub>mem</sub> : the time it takes to access something in memory

We have the following scenarios:

- read hit: value is found in cache, only t<sub>cache</sub> is required
- read miss: value is not found in cache, ( t<sub>cache</sub> + t<sub>mem</sub> )
- write hit: writes to both cache and main memory, ( t<sub>cache</sub> + t<sub>mem</sub> )
- write miss: writes directly to main memory, ( t<sub>cache</sub> + t<sub>mem</sub> )

The [wikipedia flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asP5f.png) for write through/no write allocate shows that we always have to go through the cache first, even though we aren't populating the cache. Why, if we know a write will never populate the cache in this situation, can't we only spend t<sub>mem</sub> performing the operation, rather than ( t<sub>cache</sub> + t<sub>mem</sub> )? It seems like we are unnecessarily spending extra time checking something we know we will not update.

My only guess is Paul A. Clayton's comment on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23361801/2555627) regarding this type of cache is the reason we still have to interact with the cache on a write. But even then, I don't see why the cache update and the memory update can't be done in parallel.

Comment: feel free for any queries.

Comment: But in your model `tcache` is time required for both **searching** and **writing** the cache. And this is actually a very low quality approximation, since search and write are two unrelated concepts. Sometimes we'll just do search without writing. In any case there's no way to reduce that time to zero, since at least the search will always be required to detect a cache miss. For which reason it is unclear how you are proposing to reduce a write miss to a mere `tmem`. That's just impossible.

Comment: Let me try rephrasing. I agree with you that it is necessary to **search** and **write** to the cache, because a write-through must update the cache (as well as the memory) when there is a cache hit.
However, our write to memory happens *regardless* of a hit or miss. Why can we not do these in parallel, so that our total time is `MAX(tcache, tmem)`, where I assumed that it reduces simply to `tmem`since that will be the slower one.